# how can I remove button bottom border

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-button

[image]
I want to use custom background on android button without any border and with radius only on top of the button and I make the drawable like that but the problem I got a gray line in the bottom of the button how I can remove it I already using            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless" but it didn't make anything

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/turquoise" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="14dp"
            android:topRightRadius="14dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <size android:height="60dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and here is the button used in the layout

```
<Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_bg"
      style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:clickable="false"
      android:background="@drawable/custom_bg_white"
      android:textSize="14sp"
      android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: this gray line is not border it's the elevation that is made by the button style if you don't want it set 'android:elevation=0dp'

Comment: try `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` to the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this gray line is not border it's the elevation that is made by the button style if you don't want it set `android:elevation=0dp` and set `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`

Comment: I add android:elevation=0dp now but it didn't remove the gray line

Comment: can you try this too android:stateListAnimator="@null"

Answer (score 0):

Replace your drawable file with below code and check

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="14dp"
                android:topRightRadius="14dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size android:height="60dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    </layer-list>
```

or Share your full xml layout file code